# Is it possible in salesforce to fetch All Buttons (Standard objects and Custom) meta deta

Tags: soql, metadata-api, metadata

Is there any way i can fetch meta data for custom button. I want to query all values for custom button to check if there is String hardcoded in that .

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be more clear what you are looking for.

Comment: Are you looking for hard coded Ids? [If so there's a tool for that built into Salesforce.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Updating-Hard-Coded-References-FAQ&type=1)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible through the metadata api. All buttons and links are returned on their related object as [WebLinks](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_weblink.htm).

When retrieving metadata through a retrieve call, you just need to set your package.xml manifest to retrieve all `CustomObject`s.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <version>39.0</version>
</Package>
```